# cell2mat doesn't work: convert cell to array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

How can I convert a cell to  a string array in Matlab? For example:

```
len=5;
tmp =cell(len,1);

tmp{1,1}='a';
tmp{2,1}='bc';
tmp{3,1}='def';             


arr=[];
arr= **how to convert  tmp to string array here?**
```

How can I convert `tmp` to string array `arr` as:

```
tmp={'a'  ,  'bc'  ,  'def'}
```

so that I can pass `arr` to `cat` function:

```
cat (2,'string is', arr);
```

Comment: In your example cell2mat does work for me. Are you trying string with different length? If not, what's the error message.

Comment: @cifz  arr=cell2mat(tmp); arr(1)

arr(1) will get 's' not 'some string'

Comment: I've answered with an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing the first and second dimensions of `tmp`:

```
 tmp = cell(1, 5); 
 tmp{1}='a';
 tmp{2}='bc';
 tmp{3}='def'
```

Results with

```
 tmp = 
{'a'    'bc'    'def'     []     []}
```

Adding another string

```
 cat(2,'string is', tmp)
```

Results with

```
ans = 
{ 'string is'    'a'    'bc'    'def'     []     [] }
```